# Pycharm remote interpreter using docker-compose not working in debug mode

Tags: docker, docker-compose, pycharm, remote-debugging

I have a Pycharm remote interpreter setup using docker-compose, I am able to run the project fine but when trying to debug I am getting this error:

```
ERROR: for e21cea317159_my_proj  Cannot create container for service myproj: conflicting options: port publishing and the container type network mode
```

My docker-compose file:

```
version: '1.0'
services:
  my-router:
    image: testimage:latest
    dns: 10.10.10.10
    dns_search:
      - testwebsite.com
  et:
    build:
      context: ""
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - .:/workarea
    depends_on:
      - "my-router"
    environment:
      - WAIT_FOR_PORTS=my-router:12345
    network_mode: service:my-router
```

Thanks for the help!